# Sample rate in QAudioFormat

Tags: c++, qt

I need to capture sound from the microphone with high sample rate = 192 kHz.

The function supportedSampleRates() returns me QList [8000,11025,22050,44100,48000, 96000]. I use Realtek ALC887 and I set sample rate on settings to 192 kHz.

1) Why is 192 kHz absent in QList?

If I use 48000 and less all will work.

But if I choose 96000 signal stateChanged(QAudio::State) give StoppedState.

This is my code.

```
const int sampleRate=96000;
void initializeAudio()
{
    m_format.setSampleRate(sampleRate);
    m_format.setChannels(1);
    m_format.setSampleSize(16);
    m_format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::SignedInt);
    m_format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
    m_format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
    m_device=QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultInputDevice();
    QAudioDeviceInfo info(QAudioDeviceInfo::defaultInputDevice());
    if (!info.isFormatSupported(m_format))
    {
        qWarning() << "Default format not supported - trying to use nearest";
        m_format = info.nearestFormat(m_format);
    }   
    m_audioInfo  = new AudioInfo(m_format, this);
    connect(m_audioInfo, SIGNAL(update()), SLOT(refreshDisplay()));
    createAudioInput();
}
void RecieverPlot::createAudioInput()
{
    m_audioInput = new QAudioInput(m_device, m_format, this);
    connect(m_audioInput, SIGNAL(notify()), SLOT(notified()));
    connect(m_audioInput, SIGNAL(stateChanged(QAudio::State)),SLOT(stateChanged(QAudio::State)));
    m_audioInfo->start();
    m_audioInput->start(m_audioInfo);
    qint64 len=m_audioInput->bytesReady();
}
```

Comment: Depending on what version of Qt you're using, you might be encountering this bug:  https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-26102

Comment: Thank you. I used Qt 4.8